# Distributed Builds with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, distributed-computing

I was wondering if there is any way to do distributed compilation (as in the compilation isn't performed locally on your machine, but is compiled faster using a cloud of computers or even a single other more powerful computer) with gradle. With the gradle cache, the inputs and outputs are clearly defined, so it seems feasible. I was curious if this has been done, or if anyone has any information on it. I’ve been surprised at how little information I’ve turned up for this online.

Comment: i came here searching for the same thing .. seems very feasible -- classic distributed computing case where communication to computation ratio is very low .. but no information anywhere

Comment: yeah, we spend weeks building projects on crappy corporate laptops instead of utilizing all the power of 32-core desktop/server cpus. I've searched for a solution for years. unfortunately, the industry can't provide anything useful so far.